# How to calculate resistor needed between generator and bridge rectifier?

Tags: resistors, generator, amperage, bridge-rectifier

I am almost done with constructing my railgun however, I am stuck with this last problem. To charge my 110 V 35 mF capacitors, I am converting 120 V 30 amp AC current from a generator to a 120 V 10 amp bridge rectifier. Thus, the problem I have is figuring out what size capacitor to uses to lower the amperage from 30 to 10 so I don't blow my bridge rectifier.

Comment: Schematic, please. There's a button on the editor toolbar. You are also using some techno-babble in your question.

Comment: I'd be more worried about the 170V peak DC voltage from the bridge rectifier detonating your 110V capacitors.

Comment: I did mean 154 volts not 170 volts do'h

Answer (score 1):

As Andy points out, you have more things to worry about than the current through your bridge rectifier. You're going to need a voltage regulator, too, and you might as well use one that includes a current limiting feature as well. Problem solved.

As a side note, keep in mind that power rectifiers usually have a "one-cycle surge" capability that is frequently an order of magnitude or more greater than the continuous rating, so you may not need current limiting at all. Charging 35 mF to 110 VDC requires an energy pulse of

$$0.5 (35 mF) (110 V)^2 = 212 J$$

which, when delivered in 1/60 second is an average power of 12.7 kW, or just over 100 A. It's entirely possible that your bridge can handle this. And in any case, your generator's source impedance will probably limit the current to something less than this anyway.